# Using existing pub sub subscription from google data flow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

Am using Google Data Flow where in one of the steps am subscribing to a topic in pub sub using already created subscription.
Here is the code snippet

```
CustomPipelineOptions options =
            PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(customPipelineOptions.class);
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

    PCollection<TableRow> datastream = p.apply(PubsubIO.Read.named("Read device  data from PubSub")                 .subscription("projects/<projectID>/subscriptions/<subscriptionname>)
            .topic(String.format("projects/%s/topics/%s", options.getSourceProject(), options.getSourceTopic()))
            .timestampLabel("ts")
            .withCoder(TableRowJsonCoder.of()));
```

The above code when executed results in the following error:
 Error processing pipeline. Causes: (b5e276ef8c76419f): Unrecognized input pubsub_subscription for step s1.

Am passing the right subscription name and project ID.
Not sure why am still getting the above error.

Please kindly help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifying one of 2 sources should be enough: a topic or a subscription.

I suggest you try:

```
PCollection<TableRow> datastream = p
        .apply(PubsubIO.Read.named("Read device data from PubSub")
        .topic(String.format("projects/%s/topics/%s", options.getSourceProject(), options.getSourceTopic()))
        .timestampLabel("ts")
        .withCoder(TableRowJsonCoder.of()));
```

Also: I suppose you are using the Dataflow 1.9 SDK? You might want to think about moving to the [new Beam 2.0.0 release](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/05/17/beam-first-stable-release.html). You can find the reference for PubSub in that SDK [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/).

Comment: Hi Matthias,Thanks for the response.Let me try that and get back to you.